# Tcl - How to sort excel using tcom

Tags: tcl

Excel sorting requires specifying values in the format:

```
Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("C2"), order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes
```

How Do I send it via tcom? I have tried the following unsuccessfully

```
 (Users) 14 % set sort [$worksheet Sort]
 ::tcom::handle0x0201DD00
 (Users) 15 % $sort Header xlYes
 0x80020005 {Type mismatch.}
 (Users) 16 % $sort Header 1
 (Users) 18 % set sfs [$sort SortFields]
 ::tcom::handle0x0201DD60
 (Users) 21 % $sfs Add Key:=[$worksheet Range "B2:B7"]
 0x80020005 {Type mismatch.}
 (Users) 22 % $sfs Add [$worksheet Range "B2:B7"]
 ::tcom::handle0x0201DDA0
 (Users) 24 % $sort Apply
 0x800a03ec {Unknown error}
 (Users) 25 % $sfs Add [$application Range "B2:B7"]
 ::tcom::handle0x0201DDC0
 (Users) 26 % $sort Apply
 0x800a03ec {Unknown error}
```

Comment: The main issue over here is to how to mimic the call:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to substitute the integer value of the Excel constant rather than its name.

You can peruse the list of constants and enums at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838815.aspx and do `set xlYes [expr 1]` to ensure it's an integer, then use the variable $xlYes in your script.

If you have the Excel typelib file on your computer, you can `tcom::import` it to create a tcl array containing these constants.

more info:
How to find com object enums for tcom using registry: http://wiki.tcl.tk/19932
How one discovers the API for a COM-exporting application: http://wiki.tcl.tk/4472

Comment: I checked but i don't seem to have an excel typelib on my pc - is there a way to install it?

Comment: So I installed the excel automation dll and then it worked fine. There Excel arrays that I could use to view excel information

Comment: The API documentation does not say how to send input as key:=something - I guess I cannot do this via tcom?